# angular-auth-oidc-client v10.0.2 not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-11, angular9, angular-auth-oidc-client

I am using angular-auth-oidc-client version 10.0.2 in my angular 9 project. Everything works fine on chrome however,
If i turn the silent renew off using `silent_renew:false` and remove the `silent_renew_url`, the application works fine on IE
But if i turn the silent renew on using `silent_renew:true` and specify the `silent_renew_url: this.originUrl+'/silent-renew.html'`, the application loads a blank page on IE with the following error in console: `ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support this action`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which line does the error point to? I found some similar threads in github and the error points to `CustomEvent()` which is [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Browser_compatibility). You could check [this thread](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/228) and [this thread](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/276) to see if you have the same issue. If so, you can try the solution to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill).